# SwiftUI - tapping on an overlay of an element within a ScrollView on Mac OS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm building a list of items within a scrollview to display some kind of menu when you tap on one, and to be able to dismiss it by tapping around the displayed menu

the problem i'm facing is that in this configuration, the overlay seems to allow tapping through depending on what's under. for example, if it's a button, tapping on the overlay is ignored, and the button under it is pressed instead

I've illustrated this in an example below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dropdown = false

    var innerView: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 300) {
            Button {
                print("pressing blank button")
            } label: {
                Text("Blank")
            }

            if dropdown {
                Text("Is Open")
                    .overlay(
                        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                            Color.blue.opacity(0.8)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .frame(width: 9999, height: 9999)
                                .position(x: 0, y: 0)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    dropdown = false
                                }

                            VStack {
                                Text("menu item 1").padding()
                                Text("menu item 2").padding()
                                Text("menu item 3").padding()
                            }
                            .background(.green)
                            .frame(minWidth: 200, alignment: .topTrailing)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 50)

                        , alignment: .topTrailing
                    )
                    .zIndex(1000)
            } else {
                Button {
                    dropdown = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Open")
                }
            }

            Button {
                print("pressing blank button")
            } label: {
                Text("Blank")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            innerView
                .frame(width: 800, height: 1000)
        }.frame(width: 800, height: 1000)
    }
}
```

The visual result is below, where if i tap on any "Blank" buttons, they get pressed, even if the blue element is on top of them. If tapping around the buttons, the blue element does get pressed

**This doesn't happen if the view isn't contained in a scrollview**

[image]

And the question is why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong? Or is there a better way to achieve this effect? meaning the ability to open a custom designed dropdown at a certain location in a view, and have some way of dismissing it (like clicking anywhere around it)

Comment: Not click-through with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4, so works fine (although I'd say it is weird layout)

Comment: i haven't tested on ios, only mac

Comment: You tagged question as iOS